# Mocks para dois testes semelhantes não foram chamados

Tags: testes, jest, mock

Fala galera beleza, estou com um problema. Estou tentando testar uma chamada axios e toast, vamos ao meu codigo de teste, aqui está:
register.test.js:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "../../test-utils/index";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import RegisterOficio from "../../components/RegisterOficio";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

jest.mock("axios");
jest.mock("react-toastify");
const mockedUseNavigate = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
useNavigate: () => mockedUseNavigate,
}));

test("submit form is sent successfully", async () => {
axios.post.mockResolvedValue({
data: "Pedido de oficio cadastrado com sucesso",
});
const user = userEvent.setup();
render(<RegisterOficio tipoRequer={"Oficio"} />);
const inputNumOficio = screen.getByLabelText(/numero do oficio/i);
await user.type(inputNumOficio, "20230312345");
expect(inputNumOficio).toHaveValue("20230312345");
const inputSecretaria = screen.getByLabelText(/secretaria/i);
await user.type(inputSecretaria, "PGM");
expect(inputSecretaria).toHaveValue("PGM");
const inputNumProcesso = screen.getByLabelText(/nº do processo/i);
await user.type(inputNumProcesso, "1445/2023");
expect(inputNumProcesso).toHaveValue("1445/2023");
const inputDate = screen.getByLabelText(/data que foi pedido/i);
await user.click(inputDate);
await user.type(inputDate, "2023-12-05");
expect(inputDate).toHaveValue("2023-12-05");
const inputNome = screen.getByLabelText(/quem pediu/i);
await user.type(inputNome, "Any");
expect(inputNome).toHaveValue("Any");
await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /enviar/i }));
await waitFor(() => {
expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  "http://localhost:3030/register/oficio",
  {
    tipo_requer: "Oficio",
    secretaria: "PGM",
    numoficio: "20230312345",
    date: "2023-12-05",
    numprocesso: "1445/2023",
    name: "Any",
    anexos: [],
  }
);
});
await waitFor(() => {
expect(toast.success).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  "Pedido de oficio cadastrado com sucesso"
);
});
await waitFor(() => {
expect(mockedUseNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/main");
});
});

test("error in axios request", async () => {
axios.post.mockRejectedValue({ response: { data: "Erro no servidor" } });
render(<RegisterOficio tipoRequer={"Oficio"} />);
 await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /enviar/i }));
await waitFor(() => {
console.log(axios.post.mock)
});
});
```

Observando os testes o meu teste "submit form is sent successfully" está sendo chamado os mocks corretamente mockados e corretamente sendo chamados e os testes estão passando. O meu problema surge no proximo teste o "error in axios request", acontece que este console.log que está no escopo do waitfor me retorna isto: `{ calls: [], instances: [], invocationCallOrder: [], results: [] }`, ou seja, o axios.post não esta sendo chamado, o mesmo serve para o toast.error. Eu tive esse mesmo problema com o teste que esta passando o "submit form is sent successfully" a modificaçao que fez este teste passar e os mocks serem chamados, foi a exclusao de um jest.spyOn que tinha no codigo, partindo do pressuposto eu penso que algo pode estar interferindo na chamada do mock.
Alternativas que já tentei: Incluir meus mocks dentro do escopo do beforeEach e apos o jest.clearAllMocks, usar o `.mockResolvedValue(Promise.reject("Resposta mockada"))`, definir o `jest.mock("react-toastify", () => { toast: { error: jest.fn() } })` por exemplo, aguardar a chamada async no waitFor usando timeOut, `jest.advanceTimersByTime`, enfim eu já tentei de absolutamente tudo um pouco e nada conclusivo.
*Obs 1)  dar console.log(axios.post ou toast.error) me retorna a funcao mockada normal.*
A chamada que estou testando:
RegisterOficio:

```
const submitData = () => {
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3030/register/oficio", {
    tipo_requer: tipoRequer,
    secretaria: values.secretaria,
    numoficio: values.numoficio,
    date: values.date,
    numprocesso: values.numprocesso,
    name: values.name,
    anexos: arrayAnexos,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    toast.success(res.data)
    navigate("/main");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error caught:', error);
      toast.error(error.response.data);
      navigate("/register"); 
  });
```

};

resposta enviada do backend pro front em caso de error:

```
  } catch (error) {
res.status(500).json("Erro no servidor");
return;
```

}

*Obs 2) Já adicionei consoles.log na chamada e ela ocorre perfeitamente*

Agradeço encarecidamente a ajuda de voces. Obrigado